# How to stop windows from opening along the edges?

Tags: compiz

I've notice this with Ubuntu, Kubuntu and Xubuntu: whenever you open a window, it's in one of the four corners. How do I stop this and make it more like Windows where it remembers where the window was before? If I can't do that how do I make it so it opens in the centre of the screen?

Comment: simple and good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try.
Launch *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and click on *Place Windows*:

[image]

And then choose *Smart* for the placement mode:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't help. Smart makes it open on the edges. And workaround doesn't work when 'Center' is chosen.